# Unable to delete first row in matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am stuck when trying to delete the first row from the `log_returns` matrix. Essentially, I'd like to get rid of the first row because it has NaN values. I have tried `isnan()` without joy, and finally landed on the `numpy.delete()` method which sounds most promising but still doesn't achieve the purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import numpy as np

symbols = ['XOM', 'CVX', 'SLB', 'PXD', 'EOG', 'OXY', 'HAL', 'KMI', 'SE', 'PSX', 'VLO','COP','APC','TSO','WMB','BHI','APA','COG','DVN','MPC','NBL','CXO','NOV','HES','MRO','EQT','XEC','FTI','RRC','OKE','SWN','NFX','HP','MUR','CHK','RIG','DO']

try:
    h9 = pd.HDFStore('port.h9')
    data = h9['norm']
    h9.close()
except:
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for sym in symbols:
        data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, data_source='yahoo',
                                start='1/1/2010')['Adj Close']
    data = data.dropna()
    h9 = pd.HDFStore('port.h9')
    h9['norm'] = data
    h9.close()

data.info()
log_returns = np.log(data / data.shift(1))
log_returns.head()
np.delete(log_returns, 0, 0)
```

The last line (to delete) above throws the following exception, which doesn't make sense as `row = 0`, `location = 0` is surely not out of scope of the `log_returns` matrix which is of shape (1116,37).

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (37, 1115), indices imply (37, 1116)
```

Comment: what about: `log_returns  = log_returns.iloc[1:]`?

Comment: The second argument of [`np.delete()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) is probably not what you think it is. If you just need to throw away the first row, @MaxU's suggestion is the way to go. Also, `np.nan!=np.nan` would make `np.delete`'s job even harder.

Comment: MaxU -- the iloc method worked a treat! Thanks much. Also thank you Andras for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```
In [202]: from pandas_datareader import data as web

In [218]: df = web.DataReader('XOM', 'yahoo', start='1/1/2010')['Adj Close']

In [219]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 10

In [220]: df
Out[220]:
Date
2010-01-04    57.203028
2010-01-05    57.426378
2010-01-06    57.922715
2010-01-07    57.740730
2010-01-08    57.509100
                ...
2016-09-12    87.290001
2016-09-13    85.209999
2016-09-14    84.599998
2016-09-15    85.080002
2016-09-16    84.029999
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64

In [221]: np.log(df.head(10).pct_change() + 1)
Out[221]:
Date
2010-01-04         NaN
2010-01-05    0.003897
2010-01-06    0.008606
2010-01-07   -0.003147
2010-01-08   -0.004020
2010-01-11    0.011157
2010-01-12   -0.004991
2010-01-13   -0.004011
2010-01-14    0.000144
2010-01-15   -0.008214
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

Solution:

```
In [224]: np.log(df.pct_change() + 1).dropna()
Out[224]:
Date
2010-01-05    0.003897
2010-01-06    0.008606
2010-01-07   -0.003147
2010-01-08   -0.004020
2010-01-11    0.011157
                ...
2016-09-12    0.005169
2016-09-13   -0.024117
2016-09-14   -0.007185
2016-09-15    0.005658
2016-09-16   -0.012418
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

or:

```
In [225]: np.log(df.pct_change() + 1).iloc[1:]
Out[225]:
Date
2010-01-05    0.003897
2010-01-06    0.008606
2010-01-07   -0.003147
2010-01-08   -0.004020
2010-01-11    0.011157
                ...
2016-09-12    0.005169
2016-09-13   -0.024117
2016-09-14   -0.007185
2016-09-15    0.005658
2016-09-16   -0.012418
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

or:

```
In [227]: np.log(df.pct_change() + 1).drop(df.index[0])
Out[227]:
Date
2010-01-05    0.003897
2010-01-06    0.008606
2010-01-07   -0.003147
2010-01-08   -0.004020
2010-01-11    0.011157
                ...
2016-09-12    0.005169
2016-09-13   -0.024117
2016-09-14   -0.007185
2016-09-15    0.005658
2016-09-16   -0.012418
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```